# Routes missing for Laravel Backpack admin

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-backpack

We have several Laravel applications that use Backpack for the admin panel. A developer wrote a package that used Single sign-on.  We have removed this package as it was not working correctly. Once Composer was used to updating Laravel and remove the package, there are NO routes to deal with admin login. Our applications use Laravel 5.8/6 and Backpack 3.6/4.0.

I created another test application with Laravel 5.8 using Backpack 3.6, and the routes are available for login. As you can see, all the login routes are available.

[image: fresh install routes available]

If you look at the following image, you can see the login routes are all missing.

[image: removed SSO package no login routes available]

Is there a way to add the routes in again? Laravel Backpack is still installed, but I need to re-register the routes.

All the settings in the application are set to default. I have even made the default authentication guard in config/auth.php to Backpack.

**config/auth.php**

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'backpack',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
],
```

**config/backpack/base.php**

```
'route_prefix' => 'admin',
'setup_auth_routes' => false,
'setup_dashboard_routes' => true,
'setup_my_account_routes' => true,
'user_model_fqn' => App\Models\BackpackUser::class,

'middleware_class' => [
    App\Http\Middleware\CheckIfAdmin::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    // \Backpack\Base\app\Http\Middleware\UseBackpackAuthGuardInsteadOfDefaultAuthGuard::class,
],

// Alias for that middleware
'middleware_key' => 'admin',
'authentication_column'      => 'email',
'authentication_column_name' => 'Email',
'guard' => 'backpack',
'passwords' => 'backpack',
```

**config/backpack/permissionmanager.php**

```
'models' => [
    'user' => App\Models\BackpackUser::class,
    'permission' => Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Models\Permission::class,
    'role' => Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Models\Role::class,
],

'allow_permission_create' => false,
'allow_permission_update' => false,
'allow_permission_delete' => false,
'allow_role_create'       => true,
'allow_role_update'       => true,
'allow_role_delete'       => true,

'multiple_guards' => true,
```

**app/Models/BackpackUser.php**

```
class BackpackUser extends User
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasRoles;
    use InheritsRelationsFromParentModel;

    protected $table = 'users';
    
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
    
    public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

So pretty much standard settings. I cannot figure out why the routes are not registered and available. If you get to http://localhost/admin, I get redirected to http://localhost/admin/login, which gives a 404 error. Can anyone help?

Comment: I have already tried   php artisan optimize:clear   and also composer dump-autoload but the routes are not appearing.  How do I register the routes again ?  Add the routes from the backpack src to routes/base.php ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable `'setup_auth_routes' => true` in `config/base.php`. This will allow Backpack to use the standard routes. Then the second step is to use `Auth::routes();` inside your `routes/web.php`

If you are missing some/all of the controllers or UIs then you can scaffold them:

1. Install laravel/ui part using `composer require laravel/ui`
2. Use `php artisan ui vue --auth` or `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` or `php artisan ui react --auth` depending on what you use for the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error: **Could not find Backpack view [backpack.ui::auth.login]**

What i did was,

- open file vendor\backpack\crud\src\helpers.php
- changed the line `config('backpack.ui.view_namespace').$view,`
  to `config('backpack.ui:view_namespace').$view,`

NOTE difference between **ui.view** and **ui:view**

This means it was referring to the wrong path